# What gridmix input format likes?

Tags: mapreduce, benchmarking, hadoop2

I use Rumen mine job-history files, contains job-trace.json and job-topology.json.
GirdMix usage likes:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-gridmix-2.7.3.jar -libjars $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-rumen-2.7.3.jar -Dgridmix.compression-emulation.enable=false <iopath> <trace>
```

And,  means working directory for Gridmix, so I feed with: `file:///home/hadoop/input`,  means the trace file extracted from log files, feed with `file:///home/hadoop/rumen/job-trace-1hr.json`.

Finally, meet with following Exceptions:

```
2019-03-07 16:37:12,495 ERROR [main] gridmix.Gridmix (Gridmix.java:start(534)) - Startup failed. java.io.IOException: Found no satisfactory file in file:/home//hadoop/input
2019-03-07 16:37:13,040 INFO  [main] util.ExitUtil (ExitUtil.java:terminate(124)) - Exiting with status 2
2019-03-07 16:37:13,041 INFO  [Thread-1] gridmix.Gridmix (Gridmix.java:run(657)) - Exiting...
```

So what this parameter  like , or how to use it?

can anyone have some ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: How `<iopath>` feed with ?

Answer (score 1):

I found it's my own incorrect useage;
I check out gridmix parameters usage, due to too small input data.

```
gridmix.min.file.size   |  The minimum size of the input files. The default limit is 128 MiB. Tweak this parameter if you see an error-message like "Found no satisfactory file" while testing GridMix with a relatively-small input data-set.
```

So, I tuned larger input data.
Using -generate 10G.

Thanks.